# How to pass arguments to a namespaced class constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, class, constructor, namespaces, autoload

I am writing a small project which makes use of [PHPSavant](http://phpsavant.com/) for templating.  Now, this template engine is a little out of date and doesn't use namespaces so I'm going through the code and adding them.  I'm using [PHP-FIG's](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md) autoload function for the project.

My problem is that when PHPSavant's Error class is autoloaded, it seems to be passing the arguments for the constructor to include() and I can't seem to figure out the correct way to pass arguments to a namespaced instantiation.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$err = new Savant3\Error($config);
```

And the resulting error:

```
PHP Warning:  include(): File name is longer than the maximum allowed   
platform (4096): project\sys\3p\Savant3\Savant3\Error: Array( [lots of array data])
```

And yes, there are two directories/spaces named Savant3, I didn't want to go through and rename a bunch of classes and relative directories.

So is this a problem with the autoloader or am I missing something regarding constructing namespaced classes?

Comment: Looks funny and broken. What if you "declare" the class using the `use` statement, same issue?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the autoloader you are using then.

Comment: You should check the value of the filename that's being included by your autoloader. Looks like it generates a filename that's too long, since the error comes from the include-construct and it looks like you'd be including longer filepaths. Otherwise try to include the file manually and see what happens.

Comment: I figured it out, there was something else in the templating system which wasn't properly namespaced and so it was the error reporting itself which was the problem, not namespaces or constructors.  Thanks for the help though